# how to make html work in php

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I am trying to get this PHP code working with my html. The PHP alone work but when im trying to use the html form and use PHP code it does not do anything at all. I've been trying to figure this out but without any success. Can somebody please explain what I am doing wrong?

---

```
    <?php

include_once("config.php");  
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
       //Perform the verification

       $uname = $_POST['uname'];
       $email = $_POST['email'];
       $email2 = $_POST['email2'];
       $pass = $_POST['pass'];
       $pass2 = $_POST['pass2'];

       if($email == $email2){
        if($pass == $pass2){
            //All good. Carry on.

        $query = $sql->prepare("INSERT INTO login (uname, email, pass) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
        $query->bind_param('sss', $uname, $email, $pass );
        $query -> execute();
        header("Location: index.html");

        }else{
            echo "Passwords do not match.<br />";
            exit();
            }
        }else{
            echo "Emails do not match.<br /><br />";
            exit();
            }
    $sql->close();
    $query->close();
        }
?>



<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">


            <section>               
                <div id="container_demo" >
                    <a class="hiddenanchor" id="tologin"></a>
                    <div id="wrapper">


                        <div id="login" class="animate form">
                            <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
                                <h1> Sign up </h1> 
                                <p> 
                                    <label for="usernamesignup" class="uname" data-icon="u">Username</label>
                                    <input id="usernamesignup" name="usernamesignup" required="required" type="text"/>
                                </p>
                                <p> 
                                    <label for="emailsignup" class="email" data-icon="e"> Your email</label>
                                    <input id="emailsignup" name="emailsignup" required="required" type="email"/> 
                                </p>
                                 <p> 
                                    <label for="emailsignup" class="email2" data-icon="e">Confirm your email</label>
                                    <input id="emailsignup" name="emailsignup" required="required" type="email"/> 
                                </p>
                                <p> 
                                    <label for="passwordsignup" class="pass" data-icon="p">Your password </label>
                                    <input id="passwordsignup" name="passwordsignup" required="required" type="password"/>
                                </p>
                                <p> 
                                    <label for="passwordsignup_confirm" class="pass2" data-icon="p">Please confirm your password </label>
                                    <input id="passwordsignup_confirm" name="passwordsignup_confirm" required="required" type="password"/>
                                </p>

                                <p class="signin button"> 
                                    <input type="submit" value="Sign up"/> 
                                </p>
                                <p class="change_link">  
                                    Already a member ?
                                    <a href="index.html" class="to_register"> Go and log in </a>
                                </p>
                            </form>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>  
            </section>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: did you change the file extension to `.php`?

Comment: @Akam Read question carefully, OP is saying PHP alone works. :)

Comment: Didi you check that php is enabled in your apache.conf ?
What OS, Server + Version, PHP Version are you using ?

Comment: Yes I have changed the extension to PHP

Comment: I am using XAMPP 1.7.4, Win7, PHP Version 5.3.5 so yes they are all up to date

Comment: @user2644017 Use all 4 answers to solve your problem. :)

Comment: @user2644017 and your post variables don't match. You are assigning the classes not the names to the variables you are putting in the database. This could be crashing the php and giving you a blank page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not give your submit button a name.

```
<input type="submit" value="Sign up"/>
```

Without a name, the value of the `input` won't be sent to the server. Basically submitting the form will find that `if(isset(` and skip the entire code.

Comment: Ok I did changed the name on it: <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Sign up"/>, but now it just takes me to the index like I wanted however the PHP code is still not working

Comment: Comment the `header("Location: index.html");` part until you're finished with the testing.

Comment: at the top of your script add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `ini_set('display_errors', true);` to make sure errors are being displayed.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is here, you're checking if there is a post variable named `submit`:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
```

But your form doesn't have any input named `submit`. I suggest changing to:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
```

Checking the `REQUEST_METHOD` is better because it doesn't rely on the submit button being present in the post data.

Comment: +1, was going to suggest this. Another suggestion is to create a hidden input field with a name of 'hidden' or something, and then you can still do `isset($_POST['hidden'])`, but this method is better.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the `name="submit"` attribute to your submit button. Otherwise `$_POST['submit']` will never be set, and nothing will happen.

Answer (score 0):

EXTRA TIP : Your HTML textbox name is mismatch with the $_POST variable, I'll give a short example : `<input type="text" name="usernamesignup" />` should be $_POST["usernamesignup"], not $_POST["uname"].

Comment: Thank you Mark and Mihai! With the combined help from both of you it is now working